# How to delay one of the 3 ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need help with these AJAX forms. I need the smallest one to be executed after the others and I want to delay that.

I tried to use `setTimeout()`, but it seems to not work for me.

I need that because the smaller AJAX with overalleff.php is making calculations from the other two AJAX requests.

```js
// THIS IS THE AJAX FOR THAT I WANT TO DELAY
// THIS AJAX NEED TO BE EXECUTED AFTER OTHERS
function pbutton() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "overalleff.php",
    success: function(data) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $data
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
}

var barray = [];

function cbutton() {
  $('input:radio[name="cheking"]:checked').val();
  var varies = $("#fromdate").val();
  var varies2 = $("#todate").val();
  if (varies == "" || varies2 == "") {
    alert("Please fill in all 2 fields first and then submit again");
  } else {
    barray.push(varies + "~" + varies2);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "pickingeff.php",
      data: {
        fromdate: varies,
        todate: varies2
      }
    }).done(function(msg) {});
  }
}

var sarray = [];

function abutton() {
  var varies3 = $("#fromdate").val();
  var varies4 = $("#todate").val();
  if (varies3 == "" || varies4 == "") {
    alert("Please fill in all 2 fields first and then submit again");
  } else {
    sarray.push(varies3 + "~" + varies4);
    $('#loadingmessage').show();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "packingeff.php",
      data: {
        fromdate: varies3,
        todate: varies4
      }
    }).done(function(msg) {
      $('#loadingmessage').hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$.ajax` returns a `Promise`, you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which runs a function after all other promises are over.

```
function makeThreeAjaxCalls() {
    let p1 = $.ajax("url1");
    let p2 = $.ajax("url2");
    p1.then(callback1)
    p2.then(callback2)
    Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(function() {
        $.ajax("url3").then(callback3);
    });
}
```

Comment: `function makeThreeAjaxCalls() {
var varies = $("#fromdate").val();
var varies2 = $("#todate").val();
var varies3 = $("#fromdate").val();
var varies4 = $("#todate").val();
    let p1 =  $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "pickingeff.php", data: { fromdate: varies, todate: varies2}});
    let p2 =  $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "packingeff.php", data: { fromdate: varies3, todate: varies4}});
    p1.then(callback1)
    p2.then(callback2)
    Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(function() {
        $.ajax({url: "overalleff.php"}).then(callback3);
    });
}` is that right ?

Comment: Yes. That's the idea.